# divide by 1000 column 2 to column 1000

Tags: awk, arithmetic

How can i divide as fast as possible column 2 to column 1000 by 1000?

```
awk '{printf $"{2..1000..1}"/1000}' file 1 > file2
```

Comment: You want to do what now? Please provide a sample of input/desired output, because at the moment I'm afraid the question makes less sense to us than it hopefully does to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk, as far as I know there is no way short of an explicit loop:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=1000;i++) $i /= 1000} 1' file1 > file2
```

If your system has GNU Coreutils, you could try

```
numfmt --to-unit=1K --format='%.3f' --field=2-1000 < file1 > file2
```

Depending on the scale of your input values, you may need to adjust the precision (`%.3f`).

Comment: Every time a field changes awk recombines $0 from the fields replacing FS with OFS so `awk '{for (i=2;i<=1000;i++) $i /= 1000} 1'` will cause all 1000+ fields of every input line to be recombined 999 times. Also the fact that we're using any field ($i) is causing awk to do field splitting in the first place. So that seems inefficient BUT I'm not sure there's a faster alternative since printing is slow and appending to a string is slow so anything based on `awk '{split($0,f); for (i=2;i<=1000;i++) use f[i] /= 1000` might be even slower and introduces a problem when NF>1000. You'd have to test..